# How can i achieve clickable links with just using lowdown?

Tags: linux, bash, markdown

Is there any `lowdown` parameter for the convert table of contents to clickable links? I check man page but i didn't figure out.
Maybe there have no any options for that? If that so i don't want to use `pandoc`. So is there any luck to make this possible without using large tools?

I also try'd `markdown` tool. It's have `-f flag` options but it didn't worked anyway.

```sh
echo "## [The start](#the-start)" | markdown -f toc
<a name="The-start"></a>
<h2><a href="#the-start">The start</a></h2>
```

So back to topic again.

> in *.md files;

```markdown
## [The start](#the-start)
```

I want to make this like following output.

```html
<h2 id="the-start"><a href="#the-start">The start</a></h2>
```

**Update 1**(solution with Python):

```sh
echo "## [The start](#the-start)" | python -m markdown --extension=toc
```

This python module solved my problem. However i would like to hear if it possible(i mean not too much work) to make it with unix tools like sed,awk ...

**Update 2**(Solution with bash script):

I made this script with following answer from @markp-fuso
Might be missing something but it works for now.(Any suggestion would be nice!)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

input="first-post.md"

while read -r line;do
    [[ $line =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9] ]] && echo "<p>${line##}<p>"
    [[ $line =~ ^#" " ]] && ! [[ $line =~ ^##" "\[%* ]] && echo "<h1>${line### }</h1>"
    [[ $line =~ ^##" " ]] && ! [[ $line =~ ^##" "\[%* ]] && echo "<h2>${line#### }</h2>"
    IFS='[[]()]' read -r stuff name stuff ref stuff <<< $line
    [[ $line =~ ^##" "\[%* ]] && echo "<h2 id=\"${ref//#}\"><a href=\"${ref}\">${name}</a></h2>"
done < $input
```

Inside markdown file;

```markdown
Test paragraph
0 value

# Header One

## Header Two

## [Table of contents](#table-of-contents)

## [Test]
```

It gives following output;

```html
<p>Test paragraph<p>
<p>0 value<p>
<h1>Header One</h1>
<h2>Header Two</h2>
<h2 id="table-of-contents"><a href="#table-of-contents">Table of contents</a></h2>
<h2 id=""><a href="">Test</a></h2>
```

Issue comes with `## [Test]` i didn't figure out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a strictly `bash` point of view and using some simple string processing ...

```
s='## [The start](#the-start)'

IFS='[[]()]' read -r stuff name stuff ref stuff <<< "${s}"       # break $s into 5 fields using square
                                                                 # brackets and parens as delimiters

echo "<h2 id=\"${ref//#}\"><a href=\"${ref}\">${name}</a></h2>"  # print the desired output string
```

This generates:

```
<h2 id="the-start"><a href="#the-start">The start</a></h2>
```

**NOTE:** This is (obviously) highly dependent on the format of the string stored in variable `$s`.